# Getting percentage change between selected data within a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I am trying to calculate the percentage change for two values in the same column and group them by the name column and I am having trouble.

Suppose I have the following table:

| name | day | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 1 | 87 |
| Allen | 2 | 89 |
| Allen | 3 | 95 |
| Bob | 1 | 64 |
| Bob | 2 | 68 |
| Bob | 3 | 75 |
| Carl | 1 | 71 |
| Carl | 2 | 77 |
| Carl | 3 | 80 |

I want the result to be the name and the percentage change for each person between day 3 and day 1. So Allen would be 9.2 because from 87 to 95 is a 9.2 percent increase.

I want the result to be:

| name | percent_change |
| --- | --- |
| Allen | 9.2 |
| Bob | 17.2 |
| Carl | 12.7 |

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
    with dummy_table as (
        select
            name, 
            day, 
            score as first_day_score, 
            lag(score, 2) over (partition by name order by day desc) as last_day_score
        from YOUR_TABLE_NAME
    )
    select 
        name,  
        (last_day_score - first_day_score) / first_day_score::decimal as percentage_change 
    from dummy_table where last_day_score is not null
```

Just replace YOUR_TABLE_NAME. There are likely more performant and fancier solutions, but this works.

Comment: Thank you psychpg2. For anyone interested, in order to make it show as a percentage with 2 digits after the decimal, I changed the next to last line to:  
ROUND((last_day_score - first_day_score) / first_day_score::decimal * 100,2) as percentage_change

Answer (score 0):

You can try with lag function, something like this:

```
select name, day, score, 100*(score - lag(score, 1) over (partition by name order by day))/(lag(score, 1) over (partition by name order by day)) as growth_percentage
```